# Why does ListView not virtualize my user controls?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to virtualize my user controls inside a ListView like this:

```
 <ListView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem="stackPanel1_CleanUpVirtualizedItem"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                        Height="239" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" >              

                <ListView.Items>
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Green" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Blue" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Black" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Red" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Green" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Blue" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Black" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Red" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Blue" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Black" />
                     <me:UserControl1 Backg="Green" />
                    <me:UserControl1 Backg="Green" />
                </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

but, virtualizing dosen't work, if I use a Rectangle as items, virtualzing just work, like this:

```
  <ListView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem="stackPanel1_CleanUpVirtualizedItem"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                        Height="239" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" >              

                <ListView.Items>
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Gray" ></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Green"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Orange"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Gray"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Green"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Orange"></Rectangle>
                </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

UserControl1 XAML is like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Width="20" Height="20"
            >
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="internalRect" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I use the event CleanUpVirtualizedItem to detect if virtualizing is working or not, while scrolling the view list, the event will be triggered only using Rectangles, but not the UserControl1, any idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works for Rectangles, otherwise i would have posted this as an answer. So just a suggestion: MSDN"Virtualization in a StackPanel only occurs when the items control contained in the panel creates its own item containers. You can ensure this happens by using data binding. In scenarios where item containers are created and added to the items control, a VirtualizingStackPanel offers no performance advantage over a StackPanel."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you *know* that it works with rectangles? I really doubt it, rectangles are just extremely lightweight. If you create the items statically like that there cannot be any virtualization, the items are always going to be created. You need to set an `ItemsSource` and let the control create the items, for that you can set an `ItemTemplate` which contains the user-control.